# Why isn't there a simple group_by in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class Person(models.MyModel):
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department')
    start_date = models.DateField()

class Department(models.SomeModel):
    name = models.CharField()
```

I want, in my template, to be able to create a simple table where I can group people by two attributes: `department__name` and `start_date`.

In this way, people with the same department name which started in the same date would be displayed in the same row.

I know there is a template tag called `regroup`, but I can only give three arguments, and only one of them can be the `grouper`.

Well, I thought I could do this query in my `view.py` with something like this:

```
Person.objects.all().group_by('start_date','department__name')
```

But I was wrong. There is no such method.

Any way to achieve this in a simple way?

#### Edit 1

By the same attribute I mean the classe's objects. For example:

Let's suppose this is the database:

Name | Department | Start date

Bob | Sales | 12-12-2012

Sara | Sales | 12-12-2012

John | Finance | 13-11-2012

Then the of the following function would be something like this:

function:

```
Person.objects.all().group_by('department__name', 'start_date')
```

output:

Sales | 12-12-2012 | Bob, Sara

Finance | 13-11-2012 | John

This way, Sara and John have been grouped by department **AND** start date.

Comment: What does "group people by two attributes" mean? Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my question. I hope better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what SQL group by is -- in SQL you would have to choose which of Bob or Sara would be returned for the Sales - 12/12 row, you couldn't have both. I'd do this processing in Python, there's no real SQL for what you want.

For instance, keep a dictionary of (department name, date) tuples and a list of names as values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

table = defaultdict(list)

for department, date, name in Person.objects.values_list(
        'department__name', 'start_date', 'name'):
    table[(department, date)].append(name)
```

Comment: That will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do your group_by in django is using `values` and `aggregate`.

For example, you can achieve the result you want by making it like this:

```
Person.objects.all().values('department__name', 'start_date').annotate(Count('start_date'))
```

However I believe you can not get all the names in a single string, and AFAIK you also could not do it in a simple `GROUP BY` on mysql, for example.

EDIT: just now I've understood that you want to group_by two values, so you would do something like:

```
    Person.objects.all().values('department__name', 'start_date')\
        .annotate(Count('start_date'))\
        .annotate(Count('department__name'))\
        .values_list('department__name','start_date')
```

Comment: I do not need to count how many `start_date`s I have. I just need to group the similar ones in the same row. The output what you are proposing is going to be something like: `{'start_date__count': 20}`

Comment: You can add the values_list after the annotations. I've added it on my EDIT :)